# Google Analytics - remove second URL

Tags: google-analytics

Annoyingly someone accidentally duplicated my google analytics tag on a second site and now all their site traffic has been mixed into the original sites on GA.

Could someone guide me through removing the second URL from the account?

I've looked at filters but can't get my head around it.

the property is a GA4 site.

Thanks!

Comment: This question does not appear to be programming related you may have better luck on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You looked in the right direction. You want to filter by the hostname. Note that it won't remove the historical data, it will just prevent it to get to GA in future.

Also, you can apply filters to your local reports to remove the wrong hostname-related data from them.

Besides, GA4 is still raw. It's suggested to keep both, - GA4 and UA in place and use the latter for day to day analysis while the former collects data for when UA is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it.
The saved data in Google Analytics cannot be changed.